# Кто такие командоры?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, литература

У Пушкина каменный гость — "статуя командора".
У Ильфа и Петрова командором называет себя Бендер.

А кто они вообще, командоры?

Comment: _кто такие командоры_ — это Ваш заголовок. ТАК «не можно» писать! Начало — с заглавной (большой) буквы, в конце — знак вопроса. Правильно: **Кто такие командоры?**

Comment: В Интернете же есть словари, пользуйтесь. [Командор](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/837638)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Командор - слово многозначное.
Скорее всего в ваших примерах речь идет о разных командорах. 
Пушкинский командор - видимо, условный рыцарь, Пушкин не раскрывает ни его рыцарского звания, ни связи с морем, что дает основания полагать, что здесь использовано условное наименование.

Бендер, скорее всего сравнивает себя с неким командиром, то есть капитан-командором, это морской чин и должность ему соответствующая. Наиболее известный капитан-командор - Витус Беринг.